# Irregular axis tics in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

Suppose one has a d3.js plot; At the moment I've been pulling apart the stream demo, but I'm sure this question is slightly more general.

I have some number of x points I'd like to highlight by drawing vertical lines through as labels, [sort of like the tics here](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html).

I'm not picky about data representation, so I can modify the data representation as needed. Just for concreteness sake, suppose I have the points and labels in a js array: [{point: 10, label: "L1"},{point: 39, label: "L2"}]

I'm leaning towards looping over and adding the lines, but it also feels like there must be a nicer way to do this, especially since the labels will be a mess if I do this manually.

Comment: Did you read [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)?

Comment: Looks like exactly what I was missing. Thanks!